# JQuery serialize & unserialize

Tags: jquery

Anyone provide me with an example to serialize and unserialize a form in jquery?

Comment: Here's a script to help with unserialization and repopulation of the original form: https://github.com/kflorence/jquery-deserialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

```
$('#form-id').serialize()
```

returns a string joining all the name=value pairs. Are you aware of the api?